# Changing a Marker's Position on the Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I have a MapsActivity Class, where it starts at a fixed point set on the map. I'm calling a Thread, where Map is only fully loaded, when the return is true. (I'll do a search on a DB through the Web Service where it will return me Lat and Long values ​​to play on the map, and that value will be changed every 15 seconds).

I needed to know, how do I change the position of a Marker out of the class onMapReady.

Follows the MapsActivity class

```
package com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class MapsActivity extends SupportMapFragment implements     GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
    ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
Marker marker;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-23.497444, -47.440722);
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
public Double latitude, longitude;

public ProgressDialog getProgress() {
    return progress;
}

public void setProgress(ProgressDialog progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
}

private ProgressDialog progress;

boolean teste = true;
boolean teste2 = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getMapAsync(this);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"LAT:  " + location.getLatitude() + "LONG:  " + location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

    //TESTE DE EVENTO

    progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progress.setMessage("AGUARDE ENQUANTO IDENTIFICAMOS O SERVIÇO...");
    progress.show();
    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    ThreadCarregarChamado threadCarregarChamado = new ThreadCarregarChamado();
    threadCarregarChamado.setMapsActivity(this);
    threadCarregarChamado.start();

    //CRIADO UM LOOP INFINITO, PARA QUE SÓ SEJA CARREGADO O MAPA TOTALMENTE, QUANDO O RETORNO DO CHAMADO JÁ TIVER UM FUNCIONARIO DISPONIVEL
    //E TAMBEM VINCULADO COM ESSE CHAMADO QUE FOI ABERTO
    //ENQUANTO NÃO FOR VINCULADO UM FUNCIONARIO, NÃO IRA SER EXECUTADO DAQUI PRA FRENTE
    while (teste);
    //onMapReady(mMap);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    enableMyLocation();
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Testando")
            .snippet("Population: 776733"));
}


private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermitirLocalizacao.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
    } else if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//BOTÃO PARA MUDAR CAMERA PARA POSIÇÃO ATUAL}
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); JOGA O ZOOM DIRETO NA POSIÇÃO ATUAL DO CLIENTE
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(80));
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }

    if (PermitirLocalizacao.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        enableMyLocation();
    } else {
        //resume.mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Coordenadas: " + latLng.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

public void MarcarGuincho()
{
    teste=false;
    marker.setPosition(new LatLng(-25.63356, -47.440722));
    //latLng = (-23.497444, -47.440722);

}
}
```

Now my Thread

```
package com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Conexao;
import com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.ConexaoInterface;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class ThreadCarregarChamado extends Thread implements ConexaoInterface{
private ProgressDialog progress;
private Context context;

Conexao conexao;

public MapsActivity getMapsActivity() {
    return mapsActivity;
}

public void setMapsActivity(MapsActivity mapsActivity) {
    this.mapsActivity = mapsActivity;
}

private MapsActivity mapsActivity;

@Override
public void run() {
    //conexao = new Conexao(context, this, "ThreadCarregarChamado.java");
    //conexao.execute("teste.php?","");
    try {
        depoisDownload("OK");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void depoisDownload(String result) throws JSONException {
    if(result.equals("FALSE\r"))
    {
        run();
    }
    else {
        mapsActivity.MarcarGuincho();
        ProgressDialog progress;
        progress = mapsActivity.getProgress();
        progress.dismiss();
        mapsActivity.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
}
```

In the MarcarGuincho class, this is where I need to change the position of the marker set above, but it is giving me as null for me, so this is giving error ...

Error in this line

```
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(-25.63356, -47.440722));
```

**Logcat**

```
10-02 13:29:43.628 29584-30901/com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-240709
Process: com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication, PID: 29584
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.c: Not on the main thread
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.k.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517436:11)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517436:5)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cz.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517436:176)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.q.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517436:18)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzr.getPosition(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.getPosition(Unknown Source)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.MapsActivity.MarcarGuincho(MapsActivity.java:148)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.ThreadCarregarChamado.depoisDownload(ThreadCarregarChamado.java:55)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.ThreadCarregarChamado.run(ThreadCarregarChamado.java:30)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.ThreadCarregarChamado.depoisDownload(ThreadCarregarChamado.java:60)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.ThreadCarregarChamado.run(ThreadCarregarChamado.java:30)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.ThreadCarregarChamado.depoisDownload(ThreadCarregarChamado.java:60)
at com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication.Maps.ThreadCarregarChamado.run(ThreadCarregarChamado.java:30)
Line 148 = marker.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    teste = false;
    LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(-25.63356, -47.440722);
    if(marker != null)
    {
    marker.remove();
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng1)
                .title("Testando")
                .snippet("Population: 776733"));
    }
```

Comment: Here is the error when removing the marker

10-02 13:22:53.688 20524-24441/com.example.patrickcamargo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-240710

Comment: @PatrickCamargo can you post the complete logcat (error portion of logcat)?

Comment: I answered as answer to the question logcat

Comment: @PatrickCamargo One thing is wrong in this answer, as you've already used latlng, you should either use latlng1 in the above code (my answer) or you should remove the Latlng from the starting.

Comment: Ok, mas ele não chega nem na linha do addMarker, ja da erro na hora de remover o markador(marker.remove());

Comment: Okay, but it does not even come in the line of addMarker, since the error in removing the marker (marker.remove ());

Comment: Can you see the previously created marker in `onMapReady`?

Comment: Yes, I see the right marker. When I use marker.remove () inside the onMapReady class, it removes everything normal. But when I use it in the MarcarGuincho class, it returns me with the error.